# Splice not being called in loop, id not found in array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to splice an array by parameter given from an onClick element like `deleteFavourite(2)`. Three console logs show: id (2), fired message, and saved message, but the spliced message is ignored. Why is it not hitting the if?

Function:

```
deleteFavourite: function (id) {
    console.log(id);
    console.log("fired");
    var array = this.favourites;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === id) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
            console.log("spliced");
        }
    }
    this.save();
    console.log("saved");
}
```

The array is outputted like this in Chrome

```
Array(3)
0: {id: 0, title: "↵Page 0    ", url: "/page-0/"}
1: {id: 1, title: "↵Social media    ", url: "/social-media/"}
2: {id: 2, title: "↵Get involved    ", url: "/get-involved/"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Don't mention `splice` as being the problem, when the `if` does not even "hit", as  you call it, so the `splice` is never even executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're working with an array containing plain objects, so your control should be:

```
    deleteFavourite: function (id) {
    console.log(id);
    console.log("fired");
    var array = this.favourites;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].id === id) { 
            array.splice(i, 1);
            console.log("spliced");
        }
    }
    this.save();
    console.log("saved");
}
```

Indeed, you want to compare the id inside the array with the int you passed as a parameter.

Otherwise, you're comparing an object (the array[i] is an object containing 3 attributes) to an int, which will never result as true.

Comment: Oh I see... so what I was doing is I was basically looking for the index rather than the id? This solution works really well now, I guess I just did not understand what I was doing clearly or needed a 'second pair of eyes'.

Currently, this is a favourites list in a browser. While it gets removed from the array nicely, do I need to refresh the window for the user (it shows as removed in browser when refreshed) or can I somehow do this programatically?

Comment: Exactly, so looking for this index was giving you everything contained in the array at this index. You just needed to dive one "layer" deeper into the array!

Comment: For your second question, everything depends on the tools you're using in your code, and the way you're displaying the list to the user. For example, with AngularJS, you wouldn't need to refresh the display since it works with scope and updates the view everytime the scope value changes.

If you're using jQuery for example, you can find the div which contains the list, empty it and then fill it again with the new list, it's a solution.

Comment: Ah, wonderful. It was easy indeed, just wrote a function to render the list; gathered the data, and refilled the div as you said.

Comment: However, I noticed that some records in array have no ID (it's not that it doesn't get added when adding new array object... some objects have just been there prior to me writing add code and have no IDs). How would I delete by index, or give those records an ID? Did not expect for it to turn out that way haha, even with this wonderful answer. It all comes out when testing.

Comment: You can delete them by running a loop checking if array[i].id="" or null, and then splice it. Otherwise you have to put the ID by hand depending on the order you want the data to appear (if you're sorting your array). If it doesn't matter to you, then just take your highest id +1, loop through all the "not assigned" ID records and assign an id starting to this value and incrementing with each iteration.

Comment: In my example, onClick seems to know that the record without ID is actually `0` (or it gives it a zero) so null or "" won't work. Would the latter method you mention work with this?

Comment: I guess it would, you just need to change your control with if(array[id].id==0).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't need to loop your array for that. To make it work as it is try to not compare in if statement the whole section of array to a number but only iteration of your array with a number. In my opinion this should look like this first check if element of array exist then slice it.

```
if (array[id]) {
    array.splice(id, 1);
    console.log("spliced");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Try:

```
deleteFavourite: function (id) {
    console.log("deleteFavourite: ", id);
    var array = this.favourites;

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].id === id) {  // <---- MY CHANGE
            array.splice(i, 1);
            console.log("spliced");
        }
    }
    this.save();
    console.log("saved");
}
```

You should have used `array[i].id` since the index of the items in your array does not match the actual `id` index.

### Using ES2015 [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
deleteFavourite: function (id) {
    var array = this.favourites,
        index = array .findIndex(item => item.id == id);

    if( index > -1 ){
        array.splice(index, 1);
        this.save();
    }
}
```